# Can I break this block behind spikes in stage 4-5?

Tags: witcheye

[image: map]

I haven't found the blue diamond yet in stage 4-5 (Colosseum).  The reason I ask is because I've noticed a curious block that looks breakable behind some spikes.  The Block in question is in the room just before the stage's mini boss encounter, on the left wall.

[image: Block behind spikes]

This looks suspiciously like a secret diamond location to me, although there doesn't seem to be a hidden path through the spikes, and I just bounce off (and take damage).  Is this breakable, or just a red herring?  That's the tile used so far for every breakable block I've seen in the game and I haven't seen it used otherwise up until now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to catch red guard miniboss's sword after defeating him. With it you can break the spikes and that block and take blue diamond.